# Trouble getting code to wait for asynchronous call

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I have the following code:

```
var test = true;

const getJSON = async () => {
  const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');
  const get = await response.json();
  return get;
};

if(test) {
    getJSON().then(function(response) {
      console.log('I should come first: ', response)
    });
}

console.log('I should be last');
```

I want to get the value of the API call before continuing with the block of code outside of the `if`statement. However the console statement "I should be last" always executes before waiting for the result of the API call.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Since getJSON is async you have no idea when it will run. However the "I should be last" output is ran directly after you start the async call, and the async's callback (in the `then` section) is called whenever the async function is complete

Comment: Code outside of `async` and `await` always runs even if the `async` and `await` function hasn't finished. Put the second log inside of one of two functions.